# Capacitor in series with capacitors in parallel?

Tags: capacitor

[image]

What is the equivalent capacitor when identical capaoacitors are combined in series and in parallel unevenly, like shown in the diagram.

Is it all the same as capacitance i.e just divide ESR of parallel caps and add all series ESR and voltage ratings, the position of the single, higher ESR cap makes no difference?

Comment: What has ESR got to do with this?

Comment: Redraw the circuit so you can see clearly which capacitors are connected in parallel and which one in series. Then you can use the standart equations for parallel/Series capacitors to determine the total capacitance.

Answer (score 2):

From left to right - pairs of capacitors connected in parallel and then each pair is connected in series to each other and to the rest capacitor. Equation for parallel connection is C+C, so you have 2C, 2C and C connected in series. For series you have 1/Ctotal = 1/(2C) + 1/(2C) + 1/C. Hence Ctotal = 1/(2/C) equals to 0.5uF.